# Desktop background pic flashing on & off, can’t run anything

Tags: windows, boot, windows-11

After rebooting my Windows 11 desktop to get system updates, I entered the password, the system takes a normal number of seconds to load, then the desktop background pic appeared it flashes on & off. Nothing much else is there, just start button, which I can’t click. I can’t press Win+R to get into Run. The focus seems to be changing between two things as it flashes. Any ideas please?

Comment: The flicker might be because for some reason your computer is switching continuously between two background images. Try to [Start your PC in safe mode in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-your-pc-in-safe-mode-in-windows-92c27cff-db89-8644-1ce4-b3e5e56fe234), see section "From a black or blank screen", and check your background image settings.

Comment: I've got into safe mode with command prompt  (normal safe mode still has flashing), how do I check your background image settings from there?

Comment: Check *Settings > Personalisation > Background* and report. Try to change the settings to see if that has an effect. Do I understand correctly that in Safe mode the background still flickers, but the Start button is usable?

Comment: Thanks but in safe mode, backgrund flickers but start button is not usable

Comment: Since you can boot into Safe mode, you can do [Repair Install](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/repair-install-windows-11-with-an-in-place-upgrade.418/).

Comment: Repair Install worked, thank you very much

Comment: I added an answer, please consider marking it as accepted (click the ✔ sign).

Answer (score 0):

For this problem of the poster, the solution was to do a
[Repair Install](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/repair-install-windows-11-with-an-in-place-upgrade.418/).

This operation is the same as doing a major Windows upgrade, so one
should take the same precautions.